# Is there research about the Mathematica programming paradigm?

Tags: functional-style, language-design

There seem to be lots of papers discussing the functional programming paradigm terminology for Haskell, such as monad, category theory, lambda calculus, *morphism, etc. People study concepts and theory derived from haskell in depth.

**Is there any programming language theory (PLT) research on the *Mathematica* paradigm** (such as rule-based system, term-rewriting, and other mechanisms MMA uses)? How do contemporary PLT-ers think about *Mathematica*?

It seems that they often omit *Mathematica* to some degree. Honestly, I don't know much about Haskell, but I also can't imagine that *Mathematica* is completely missing some crucial aspect of programming theory that makes it that much inferior.

Also, if the truth is "no, there aren't!,  MMA is fine and perfect!", then why aren't there as many papers as for Haskell talking about the *Mathematica* programming language?

Comment: An opinion here... I think the reason why you see lots of language research articles on languages such as Haskell is because it's very much an academically designed language, and as such a clean one. Most languages are either boring, or "dirty", mixing paradigms in ways language theorists sneer at. WL is definitely "dirty" in this sense, even if it gets things done. It's functional, but not purely so. It's term-rewriting, but surely imagining everything you see is really term rewriting is unrealistic. And it's not as popular as C, whose troubles get attention due to it. And it's proprietary.

Comment: [Yes](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/papers/), about the [MAUDE system](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/index.php?title=The_Maude_System), and [term rewriting in general](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/index.php?title=Rewriting_Logic). But I'm not aware of anything about *Mathematica* specifically. BTW, you should specify that "PLT" means "programming language technology".

Comment: And to top all of it, I think there's no formal definition of crucial parts, such as the term rewriting logic which is mostly intuitive, but a bit of a proprietary, closed-source black box. That's something to sneer at, even if it works.

Comment: I believe Roman Maeder and his group did [some work](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/showciting?cid=2795879) on this while at the ETH.

Comment: I think its a good question on which we could all pontificate. Perhaps this could fit better @ meta forum?

Comment: Somehow, I have a feeling that there is a strong correlation between the volume of research and the availability of at least one compiler for a full language, for the mainstream languages at least. This is probably another way to say what @kirma stated, because availability of the compiler implies certain degree of rigor in the language spec. Also, this seems to be a necessary but not sufficient condition - there are certainly languages which have compilers but aren't so fascinating to do research about (my gut feeling is that C++ can be an example here).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Multiple independent compilers (or interpreters, if the language is particularly dynamic) show even better rigour. For instance, Python technically has a language spec, but you can't really replicate the language by just reading and understanding it. PyPy authors had to basically reverse-engineer CPython functionality in order to provide an another indistinguishable enough implementation. They at least had the source code; in the case of WL, the source code is considered a trade secret...

Comment: @kirma Somehow I have a feeling that if the language only has interpreter(s), that isn't good enough in this context (PL research, and such). I thought about Python too, and it really doesn't compare to Haskell, ML / OCaml, Lisp / Scheme, or even C, in terms of PL research availability for it, although Python's situation is definitely much better than WL's. The PyPy folks had to introduce their own Python subset which can be statically compiled, and they have JIT, which is not quite the same as ahead of time compiler. And it's not just about being dynamic - Scheme and Lisp are dynamic too.

Comment: @kirma You said that the Wolfram language is "not purely so", while I read that it offers "_full_ support for **pure** functions and **functional** programming" (see [how Mathematica compares to other *research* languages](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/analysis/content/ResearchLanguages.html)). Which one is correct?

Comment: @user688486 Heh... I wrote that comment like seven years ago. I didn't mean that you couldn't restrict to a purely functional subset of Mathematica and perform general computation, but more that unlike some other languages it isn't the only way to do things in Mathematica, and most people don't adhere to one programming paradigm when using it. Mixing of these paradigms makes it harder to apply certain formalisms that could be applied on the implementation side if it would lack side effects entirely, for instance.

Comment: @kirma Thanks for your comments. Seven years have passed, but after searching on the Google Scholar (that is, apart from the marketing literature), I still cannot find *even* _one_ fundamental research on Mathematica's [47 paradigms](https://www.wolfram.com/language/for-experts/), which fairly shows a stark contrast with Wolfram's hype. I am definitely a big fan of Wolfram Mathematica, yet I can never understand why there is such an awkward situation.